# Is it possible to use more cpus than host cpus when use qemu-system-x86_64?

Tags: qemu, kvm

For example, I have a host which has 10 CPUs, and I use qemu-system-x86_64 to create VMs has 2CPUs. Is it possible to create 10 VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, this is called overcommitting. Please take a look at [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/form-virtualization-overcommitting_with_kvm-overcommitting_virtualized_cpus).